# Squarespace Lightbox Image Centering

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, lightbox

How Squarespace centered every image even though they have different dimensions varying between landscape and portrait images?

I've been trying different solutions all day and I can't seem to figure it out.

http://bryant-demo.squarespace.com

Take a look at their lightbox and the code for it. I tried emulating it, but I can't seem to replicate their results.

Comment: Do you want explanation how they do it, or method for centering?

Comment: I haven't found a method that works that well yet. Even width/2 and height/2 top: 50% and left: 50% doesn't work with different image dimensions when some are landscape and portrait images, or at least I can't find a solution :/

Comment: Ok, check answer... or provide (html) context (problem lies there, probably)...so we can tweak it... p.s. check fiddle in full screen..., looks better...

Answer (score 0):

Don't know what they do, as i can see they get image dimensions and many other things as attributes... but here is simple method for centering, related to screen size, that's basic calculation which is applied in their case, too, i guess. Also, there are different css methods for centering...

```
 screen_width=$(window).width();
        screen_height=$(window).height();

        img_width= $('#images img').eq(i).width();
         img_height= $('#images img').eq(i).height();

        //set to center

        $('#images img').eq(i).css('margin-top',(screen_height-img_height)/2+'px');
         $('#images img').eq(i).css('margin-left',(screen_width-img_width)/2+'px');
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/dfwosy4m/

P.S. If you set images in some other container, not body, you just have to apply same calculation, for different element.

**EDIT:**
Actually, same method works, of course, no matter if container is bigger, or smaller than image... So, simple:image center = container center, and `overflow:hidden` for the rest.

```
function centralize() {
    screen_width = $('.box').width();
    screen_height = $('.box').height();

    $('#images img').each(function(i) {

        img_width = $(this).width();
        img_height = $(this).height();

        //set to center

        $(this).css('margin-top', (screen_height - img_height) / 2 + 'px');
        $(this).css('margin-left', (screen_width - img_width) / 2 + 'px');

});
}

    centralize();
```

NEW DEMO:

**http://jsfiddle.net/dfwosy4m/3/**

P.S. Inspect elements on their page, and in my demo: you will see that same technique is used (hidden image parts will be shown by inspector)... Key is overflow:hidden for the fixed boxes, so... you should apply similar css to get desired effect.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I meant before you click on the image how it's centered inside each div even though each image is of different dimensions.

Comment: Ah, sorry, i knew that misunderstanding is in question, and that you already know how to center image ... will remove answer, this is far more interesting, their THUMBNAILS appearance... they place images in fixed boxes, and HIDE redundant parts -> you will see that parts of images are hidden, center of box = center of image, maybe will send new answer soon... :)